# Generate a random integer in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

How can I get a random integer using the `random()` function in p5.js?

For example this code:

```
var num = random(0, 1);
console.log(num);
```

outputs decimal numbers to the console.

How can I get a random integer?

Answer (score 10):

If you want integer numbers from 0 to 10, both inclusive:

```js
function setup() {
  var num = int(random(0, 11));
  print(num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Explanation:

`random(0, 11)` returns numbers from 0 to 10.999999999..., but never 11.

`int()` converts those decimal numbers to integer

`int(random(0, 11))` returns numbers between 0 and 10, both inclusives.

Comment: This is the correct approach when using P5.js. +1, but it'd be awesome if you explained exactly why this works.

Comment: Kevin, "random(a,b)" gives you numbers between a and almost b, but never b, so random(0,11) returns numbers starting at 0 to 10.999999 (but never 11), then you convert numbers to int() .....   so int(random(0,11)) will integer return numbers between 0 and 10, both inclusives.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple JavaScript as demonstrated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp)?

Excluding max value:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(random(min, max)) + min;
}
```

Including limits:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(random(min + 1, max)) + min;
}
```

Comment: I was gonna post (almost) the same. He is refering to the p5 function random, but that should work just the same. Just replace `Math.random() * (max - min)` with `random(min, max)`

Comment: Minor, but p5 also offers a `floor` function so you don't need `Math.floor`. More serious, the `+ min` at the end looks wrong. You've already got that in the call to `random()`.

Answer (score 0):

The p5.js `random()` function will always return a floating-point number (aka. decimal number). If you want an integer you can use JavaScript `Math.round()` to round the number to the nearest whole number.

To get a zero or one. The best method is:

```
Math.round(random());
```

You can also use int() to have JavaScript convert the number to an integer but it has a major problem where it simply ignores the decimals, in effect rounding the number down.
This is a problem with p5.js `random()` because `random()` will return a random number from the minimum up to **but not including** the maximum. The maximum of `random(0, 1)` is 0.99999... which `int()` always converts to 0;

This means for example:

- `random()` will never return 1. Meading `int(random())` always returns 0
- `random(0, 15)` will never return 15. Meaning `int(random(15))` would never return 15

Comment: Most rngs I've seen are exclusive of the end. This is natural when working with, for example, picking random elements from arrays, and most other applications. I'd avoid `round()`.

Answer (score -1):

So, how I would do this, is assign a floored random number to a variable.

E.G.

```
var r = Math.floor(random(0,11));
console.log(r);
```

-Valkyrie

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Floor does not round, even though it does do what we want here. The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number. It might also be good to note that to use the p5.js random method we will also need function setup(){} defined as p5.js methods are not available until inside or after setup.. we could also use p5.js floor instead of Math.floor to maybe make it look a little nicer..

Comment: Thank you! Oh, okay, haha... I'll have to be more careful when talking about things I'm not super familiar with. :-) Thanks!